# C# mvc3 Actionlink not sending parameter in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having some issues with MVC3 and Actionlink. I am dynamically building a `HTML ActionLink` using data passed from my model.

In the view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.CountriesList.Count; i++)
{

<li class="sub">@Html.ActionLink(Model.CountriesList[i].countryname, 
                                 "PageSub", new { PageID = Model.PageNo, 
                                                  countryid = Model.CountriesList[i].countryid 
                                                 })</li>

}
```

The Model.PageNo is passed from the controller and has a value. I have tested this. Every time I click on the link I am getting an error as the PageNo is not being passed as a parameter. The url outputs like below:

```
http://localhost/Pages/PageSub?countryid=196
```

I need it to be below which works when I directly enter it:

```
http://localhost/Pages/PageSub?PageID=136&countryid=196
```

This is my Controller ActionResult it directs to:

```
public ActionResult PageSub(int? PageID, int? countryid)
{

}
```

I have checked the code using developer tools and the link has been built as expected:

```
<li class="sub">
     <a href="/Pages/PageSub?PageID=136&countryid=196">
</li>
```

Has anyone had similar issues? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You probably just missed it but should it not be "i < Model.CountriesList.Count -1"?

Comment: @The_Cthulhu_Kid no the count is correct

Comment: ok, I would have thought it would go out of range, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.CountriesList[i].countryname, "PageSub", "Pages", new { PageID = Model.PageNo, countryid = Model.CountriesList[i].countryid }, null)
```